# how to loop a part of a column in php database

Tags: php, sql

[image: This is my database]

I want to select only a part of "catergorie" with the value "Shirts".

is there a way to loop though that so i can echo it?

Comment: What you have tried ..?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that screenshots are not useful for this. Instead, explain the database structure, and what you have tried to solve the problem yourself. You can [edit] this information into your question. Good luck!

Comment: Im new to php and i only have connected the database.

I have this : 

include 'db.php';
           $sqlproducten = "SELECT * FROM product1";
           $resultsqlproducten = $connect->query($sqlproducten);

i want to learn more about php

Comment: you need to provide more information about what you want. if you want to order by a column and filter the categorie column with shirt value the query will be like : SELECT * FROM product1 WHERE categorie = 'Shirts' ORDER BY DesiredColumnToOrder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query:

```
$query = SELECT * FROM `tabel_naam` WHERE `categorie` = 'Shirts'
```

Als je deze query uit de database haalt, dan kun je er doorheen loopen met:
When you use this query, you can do this to loop through it:

```
$con= mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

while($row= mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['columnname'];
}

mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Ik heb alles gedaan wat jij zei en heb de volgende error geconstateerd:  Undefined index: Shirts in C:\wamp\www\webwinkel\shop.php on line 39
Line 39: `echo $row['Shirts'];`

Comment: Het werkt nu wel, bedankt voor de hulp.  dit werkte voor mij: http://imgur.com/MHzex1d

Comment: @NankoPrinzhorn, ja tuurlijk. Shirts was een tabel naam geen kolom naam ;) Je moet inderdaad daar een kolomnaam invullen. ;) Als dit antwoord geholpen heeft, zou je hem dan kunnen accepteren?